# Could not setup Firefox profile & proxy settings & authentication in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dear Selenium Webdriver Gurus,

I have made the following Firefox profile setup changes in an attempt to pickup FireBug when launching Firefox using Selenium Webdriver 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    File fireBugFile = new File("C:/selenium-ide-1.9.0.xpi");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.addExtension(fireBugFile);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "proxyserver");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "80");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.9.0");

    String urlStrProxy = "http://www.example.com/",
    proxy = "proxyserver",
    port = "80",
    username = "jack",
    password = "XXXXXXX";

    Authenticator.setDefault(new SimpleAuthenticator(username,password));
    Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
    systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxy);
    systemProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort","80");

    WebDriver driverMainPage = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
}

public class SimpleAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
   private String username, password;

   public SimpleAuthenticator(String username,String password)
   {
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
   }

   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
   {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password.toCharArray());
   }
}
```

Also trying to include proxy settings & authentication detail with additional statements to get through proxy server without 
having to manually enter them in through a pop up screen when Firefox is accessing www.abc.com without success:

Also added "-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyserver -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyUser=jack -Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXXXXX" as the JVM option.

I am running Java 7, Selenium 2.25.0, Netbeans 7.2 on Windows XP & 7.

None of the searches have directly answered this question.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the port number should be an integer in

**`firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 80);`**

And for handling the pop up asking for username and password you can use **autoit**.

Comment: Thanks Abhi_Mishra for your response. How about the issue of not able to load Firebug when launching Firefox through by using firefoxprofile in Selenium Webdriver? Thanks, Jack

Answer (score 0):

As per provided code, selenium ide is provided instead of firebug. look it

```
  File fireBugFile = new File("C:/selenium-ide-1.9.0.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(fireBugFile);
```

so this may be issue why fire bug not getting.. provide correct location of fire bug with correct version w.r.t firefox version.

for authentication, back ago i used below one without thinking about firefox profile.

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

And also created firefox profile manually and done authentication for the profile. i called this profile in execution and this way also works very well in case of firefox.

Thanks